# Grails JS minify plugin

Tags: javascript, grails, minify

I'm looking for a Grails plugin that can minify JS files (*.js.gsp) at war creation time. These files may contain some grails code like this :

```
<g:each var="..." in "...">
    ...
</g:each>
```

And that's why I can't use [YUI compressor](https://github.com/frontlinesms/grails-yui-war-minify-plugin) for example. Does anyone know a plugin that could do that ?

Comment: When you say compression what do you mean? Do you mean JS minification or servlet HTTP compression?

Comment: Minification. I should edit my post, you're right.

Comment: If you have dynamic groovy parts in your javascript, i don't think this is possible, because at runtime the code has to be evaluated. This is the main downside of this approach and leads to the [roca-recommendation](http://roca-style.org/) to not use dynamic assets at all. When removing the dynamic parts, you can easily use asset-pipeline to minify your assets (js as well as css).

Answer (score 0):

Use [Granule](https://code.google.com/p/granule/) to do the following on your gsp file:

```
<g:compress>
    <g:each var="..." in "...">
        ...
    </g:each>

    ...

</g:compress>
```